# Error in converting batch to exe using IExpress

Tags: batch-file, iexpress

I am Converting my batch file to .exe file i have added .sql file and jpg file 
i have successfully created package but when i am run this package i am getting an error like this

```
C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP001.TMP>set /p dbnm=ENTER THE DATABASE SERVICE NAME
ENTER THE DATABASE SERVICE NAME UAT

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Thu Dec 20 15:16:01 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:\Users\DEVELO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP001.TMP\\harsh.sql"
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ECHO is on..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Press any key to continue . . .
my batch file path is D:\harsh
```

need help any answer?

Comment: How you've created the package? May you'll have to copy whole the content of your package somewhere in temp with your post install script just to be sure that you have everything in tact.

Comment: You'll have to include more information to get help. The problem appears to be with the files/commands you're bundling into the SFX, but you haven't provided any of those.